# Conversion error when using case statement - Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
select *, 
case when prod='CPU' and quan>1000 then 1000
     when prod='MOUSE' and quan>1024 then 1024
     when prod='MONITOR' and quan<2 then 2 else quan end as quan
from products_test;
```

I'm getting the error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'CPU' to data type int.

Comment: Okay, `prod` is an `int`.  Why are you comparing it to the string value `'CPU'`?

Comment: post your product_test data

Comment: He probably has data that in the table where prod is an int and doesn't realize.

Comment: Why are you passing string value to Data-Type int?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the column 'prod' is of datatype nvarchar(50). It is not of datatype int.. I have checked this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** In light of the following comment from author of question

> I changed the code code as described by you, but it's still throwing
>   an error. "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value
>   '23787.1' to data type int"

It looks like `quan` in `varchar` type rather than `numeric` and also it  with the change in error it has been confirmed that `prod`  is defined as `integer`.

```
select *, 
case when CAST(prod AS VARCHAR(MAX))='CPU' and CAST(quan as DECIMAL(10,4))>1000 then 1000
     when CAST(prod AS VARCHAR(MAX))='MOUSE' and CAST(quan as DECIMAL(10,4))>1024 then 1024
     when CAST(prod AS VARCHAR(MAX))='MONITOR' and CAST(quan as DECIMAL(10,4))<2 then 2 else  CAST(quan as DECIMAL(10,4)) end as quan
from products_test;
```

> **Old answer:** Please try this modified query :
>
> ```
> select *, 
> case when CAST(prod AS VARCHAR(MAX))='CPU' and quan>1000 then 1000
>      when CAST(prod AS VARCHAR(MAX))='MOUSE' and quan>1024 then 1024
>      when CAST(prod AS VARCHAR(MAX))='MONITOR' and quan<2 then 2 else quan end as quan
> from products_test;
> ```
>
> if this works successfully, the `Prod` is in fact defined as `int` and
>   you can never get the `then` (true case) values in `CASE`  statements.

You probably need to compare codes or foreign keys from master table which has values of `'CPU', 'MOUSE' and 'MONITOR'` with prod.

Comment: @Abhi . . . I realize you accepted this answer, so you must've found that somehow it works.  However, from the perspective of SQL Server, it is going to generate the same conversion error for an invalid formatted number, regardless of whether the conversion is implicit or explicit.